# Build step failing for TeamCity and Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: c#, deployment, tfs, teamcity

**Updated with images.**

When setting up a project in TeamCity, I cannot get the build step to work. I get the same 
error every time.

> Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa\Main\Solution.sln

I am able to connect to the TFS. Where I put the root as following.

$/Projectname/

Testing the connection returns ok.

When creating the build step I use MSBuild and set the Build file path to where the solution exists in the tfs structure. So for example.

Build file path: Main\MySolution.sln

Because in the TFS this is where the solution is. $/Projectname/Main/MySolution.sln. When I run the build step I get the error above. What am I doing wrong? The 42c94c0380966ffa folder is created on disc but it is empty.

LOG

```
[14:55:24]Checking for changes
[14:55:25]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:55:25][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[14:55:25]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[14:55:25]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa
[14:55:25]Updating sources: server side checkout
[14:55:25][Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[14:55:25][Updating sources] Transferring cached clean patch for VCS root: EEL TFS
[14:55:25][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[14:55:25][Updating sources] Removing C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa
[14:55:25][Updating sources] Updating C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa
[14:55:25]Step 1/1: Build Solution (MSBuild) (2s)
[14:55:25][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa /msbuildPath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
[14:55:25][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa
[14:55:28][Step 1/1] Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\42c94c0380966ffa\Main\MySolution.sln
[14:55:28][Step 1/1] Process exited with code -42
[14:55:28][Step 1/1] Step Build Solution (MSBuild) failed
[14:55:28]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:55:28][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[14:55:28]Build finished
```

My VCS root configuration, username and password removed.

[image: http://imgur.com/IdsNEcr,Pb3qwAu#1]

And where the solution is located.

[image: http://imgur.com/IdsNEcr,Pb3qwAu#0]

And the build step

[image: http://imgur.com/HOpBiV2]

Version control settings

[image: http://imgur.com/oQMwI7L,boMqT8Z#1]

General settings

[image: http://imgur.com/oQMwI7L,boMqT8Z#0]

Comment: If no code is being put into the work folder, your VCS root configuration is wrong.  It would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of it (blurring out the connection data, of course).

Comment: Updated with screenshots of the entire setup.

Comment: Please also add 1.) a screenshot of the VCS general settings page (you posted a screenshot of the actual vcs root edit screen) and 2.) the source location (cropped out of the source control explorer screenshot).

Comment: Added some more pictures. Not sure what you mean by 2, the source location is already posted.

Comment: Given what you've posted, it looks like you are configured correctly.  Make sure you don't have a windows explorer or command prompt instance opened to any level of depth inside of the destination path.  I.e., if you're trying to watch TeamCity pull files to the folder, it'll get a write-lock exception.  Also, what security context is TeamCity running under?  Is it local system or a named account?

Comment: Both the build agent service and the build server agent is running as Local System. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that should be fine.  It means you shouldn't have a permissions issue since the service is fully permissioned.  Without being on site to help, it's gonna be hard to suggest a solution.  Two other things I would try are running Process Monitor to observe the behavior and confirm it's not a write issue and consider setting up an additional build agent on a separate box to see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: Since you posted images with the solution file name, can you update your MSBuild error message to reflect the correct name?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've configured your build to look for MySolution.sln but in TFS it's actually called EEL B2C.sln.